# Is there a setting to alter the time duration before "resetting" a keyboard entry for selecting a file

Tags: windows, keyboard, shortcuts

I like to use the keyboard to navigate files in Windows explorer (speed!).
I used to use XP quite a bit, but now in Win 7 there's something annoyingly different:

Let's say I'm in a folder with files entitled: apple.txt, bacon.txt, carrot.txt, eagle.txt
If I wanted to select the bacon.txt file, I'd type an "b".  Bam!  Really fast.

Let's say I make a mistake & type "d" (there's no file starting with "d"), I could have swore that in XP I could IMMEDIATELY type "b", and BAM, bacon.txt is selected.

In Windows 7, if I mistakenly type the "d", then IMMEDIATELY type the "b", I get the annoying "bing" sound and no file is highlighted.  I am forced to wait about 1 second before Win 7 allows me to correct myself.  I seems a small amount of time, but it is annoying.

I've found I can hit "esc", but it's pretty far on the keyboard, so that solution is a bit slow for me.

I'm hoping (guessing) there's a setting for that ~ 1 sec duration.  Does anyone know how to change this duration (is it in the registry?)?

Comment: confirmed, the same delay for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it may be **hardcoded** inside some *system dll*. So chances are that you have to do some hacky edits with hex editors or something. There's little to no information about this so you're either stuck with:

1. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> (it's not really that far).
2. Wait `1 second` to redo your direct search.